# SSH Keys for root user and normal user in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

When I put the SSH key inside `authorized_keys` for root, can I SSH in to the server as a different user without having the `authorized_keys` for that user?

Comment: Looks duplicated with [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/434896).

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't. Each user (including root) has their own `~/.ssh` folder where the authorized keys are kept. Adding them to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` will make them available to the `root` user only. If you want to authorize more users, you will have to use their own `authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 0):

Each user has their own `.ssh` folder with auth keys.  However, you can achieve (what I think you are trying to do) by going to the first server and typing the command.

```
ssh-copy-id root@server-you-need-to-connect-to.com
```

enter your password once.

Your key is copied to that user now.

Repeat for other users that you need to connect as  e.g. `$ ssh-copy-id user@server.com`

Comment: I think OP goal was to avoid repeating the command for every user...